# CSS: How can I separate this CSS snippet?

Tags: css

I've found a code snippet but I can't separate it. The problem is that my page can't understand this type of css so is there a way to separate it into normal CSS without the `&` etc.?

```
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid gray;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;

    // Success icon
    &.f-modal-success,
    &.f-modal-error {
        border-color: #004;

        &:after,
        &:before {
            background: #fff;
            content: '';
            height: 120px;
            position: absolute;
            transform: rotate(45deg);
            width: 60px;
        }

        &:before {
            border-radius: 120px 0 0 120px;
            left: -33px;
            top: -7px;
            transform-origin: 60px 60px;
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }

        &:after {
            border-radius: 0 120px 120px 0;
            left: 30px;
            top: -11px;
            transform-origin: 0 60px;
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }

        .f-modal-placeholder {
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 4px solid rgba(0, 222, 180, .5);
            box-sizing: content-box;
            height: 80px;
            left: -4px;
            position: absolute;
            top: -4px;
            width: 80px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .f-modal-fix {
            background-color: #fff;
            height: 90px;
            left: 28px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 8px;
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
            width: 5px;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .f-modal-line {
            background-color: #00deb4;
            border-radius: 2px;
            display: block;
            height: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;

            &.f-modal-tip {
                left: 14px;
                top: 46px;
                transform: rotate(45deg);
                width: 25px;
            }

            &.f-modal-long {
                right: 8px;
                top: 38px;
                transform: rotate(-45deg);
                width: 47px;
            }
        }
    }

    // Error icon
    &.f-modal-error {
        border-color: #abc;

        .f-modal-x-mark {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .f-modal-placeholder {
            border: 4px solid rgba(170, 0, 0, .5);
        }

        .f-modal-line {
            background-color: #aa0000;
            top: 37px;
            width: 47px;

            &.f-modal-left {
                left: 17px;
                transform: rotate(45deg);
            }

            &.f-modal-right {
                right: 16px;
                transform: rotate(-45deg);
            }
        }
    }
}

.animateSuccessTip {
    animation: animateSuccessTip .75s;
}

.animateSuccessLong {
    animation: animateSuccessLong .75s;
}

.f-modal-icon.f-modal-success.animate:after {
    animation: rotatePlaceholder 4.25s ease-in;
}

.f-modal-icon.f-modal-error.animate:after {
    animation: rotatePlaceholder 4.25s ease-in;
}

.animateErrorIcon {
    animation: animateErrorIcon .5s;
}

.animateXLeft {
    animation: animateXLeft .75s;
}

.animateXRight {
    animation: animateXRight .75s;
}
```

Comment: Its using SCSS. You need to compile it to CSS. Or you could simply rewrite it long hand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's written in Sass/Scss, a CSS preprocessor. It is a scripting language that extends CSS. Sass/Scss must be compiled into CSS, for the browser to understand it.

To convert it into CSS, you should have a proper Sass/Scss compiler, watching your changes, and compiling your Sass/Scss into CSS on the fly. Or you can run it manually in an online Sass/Scss to CSS converter, like this one: https://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/

So you would get a normal CSS:

```
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-success, .f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error {
  border-color: #004;
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-success:after, .f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error:after, .f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-success:before, .f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error:before {
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 60px;
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-success:before, .f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error:before {
  border-radius: 120px 0 0 120px;
  left: -33px;
  top: -7px;
  transform-origin: 60px 60px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-success:after, .f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error:after {
  border-radius: 0 120px 120px 0;
  left: 30px;
  top: -11px;
  transform-origin: 0 60px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-success .f-modal-placeholder, .f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error .f-modal-placeholder {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgba(0, 222, 180, .5);
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 80px;
  left: -4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  width: 80px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-success .f-modal-fix, .f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error .f-modal-fix {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 90px;
  left: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-success .f-modal-line, .f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error .f-modal-line {
  background-color: #00deb4;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-success .f-modal-line.f-modal-tip, .f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error .f-modal-line.f-modal-tip {
  left: 14px;
  top: 46px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 25px;
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-success .f-modal-line.f-modal-long, .f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error .f-modal-line.f-modal-long {
  right: 8px;
  top: 38px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 47px;
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error {
  border-color: #abc;
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error .f-modal-x-mark {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error .f-modal-placeholder {
  border: 4px solid rgba(170, 0, 0, .5);
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error .f-modal-line {
  background-color: #a00;
  top: 37px;
  width: 47px;
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error .f-modal-line.f-modal-left {
  left: 17px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.f-modal-alert .f-modal-icon.f-modal-error .f-modal-line.f-modal-right {
  right: 16px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.animateSuccessTip {
  animation: animateSuccessTip 0.75s;
}
.animateSuccessLong {
  animation: animateSuccessLong 0.75s;
}
.f-modal-icon.f-modal-success.animate:after {
  animation: rotatePlaceholder 4.25s ease-in;
}
.f-modal-icon.f-modal-error.animate:after {
  animation: rotatePlaceholder 4.25s ease-in;
}
.animateErrorIcon {
  animation: animateErrorIcon 0.5s;
}
.animateXLeft {
  animation: animateXLeft 0.75s;
}
.animateXRight {
  animation: animateXRight 0.75s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I never did something with SCSS so your answer is vey helpful.